# Show Protected OS files using cmd.exe

Tags: windows-7, windows-command-prompt

I'm trying to deploy shortcuts from xcopy using a batch script to `c:\users\all users\desktop` But this is a hidden folder with `Hide Protected operating System files` tick box under Folder options.

I need to run a command to allow me access copy a file to this directory.

So far I've tried running `attrib -h c:\users\all users\`, but it hasn't helped.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: No the command completed successfully but that's only because it wasn't the correct command to run. The Attrib command doesn't seem to remove the tick box for "hide Protected OS System Files"

Comment: No, when you xcopy the files into that directory, you probably get an error, else you wouldn't ask this question I asume.

Comment: Of course.. command I'm running is:
xcopy "c:\NOCapps1\Shortcuts\*.*" c:\Users\All Users\Desktop
Error: Invalid Number of Parameters
0 File(s) copied...

I run the same command but point it to my profile and it works.

Comment: Try putting the second one in " as well: `xcopy "c:\NOCapps1\Shortcuts*.*" "c:\Users\All Users\Desktop"`  this is most likely the error ("All Users" has a space, your profile probably doesn't)

Comment: Using your suggestion I get Access denied

Comment: OK, now we're a step further. Do you have access to the directory? (ACL)?

Comment: @Jaoibh 1. this flag has no effect on batch files, it's only for Windows Explorer. 2. In addition to @MichelZ advice, you should have administrator privilegies to write to public desktop (and don't change these permissions to avoid messing something by mistake) 3. To successfully XCOPY , see XCOPY /?. I usually use a lot of flags to copy well (like `/E /C /I /G /H /K /Y`)

Answer (score 1):

C:\Users\All Users in windows 7 is a Symlink to the C:\ProgramData folder. The C:\Programdata\desktop folder is a junction back to c:\users\public\desktop.

If you are trying to copy data to the "all users\desktop" folder, try copying the shortcut directly to the C:\users\public\Desktop folder.

Comment: problem is non-quoted path with spaces and lack of privilegies, not a symlink.

Comment: I've tried xcopy "c:\NOCapps1\shortcuts\*.*" "c:\programdata\desktop" and I get access denied

I've also tried copying directly to the public\desktop folder and get access denied also.

Answer (score -1):

Off the back of @MichelZ, @Rex and @LogicDaemon's suggestions I found the solution

```
xcopy "c:\NOCapps1\shortcuts\*.*" /i "c:\users\public\public desktop\"
```

Comment: The problem isn't resolved copying to the Public desktop doesn't put the files on every users desktop as I'd hoped.